# Rust - как в векторе удалить пустые элементы?

Tags: rust

Есть вектор, который собирается из строки через разбивку:

```
let mut _strings: Vec<&str> = _string_from_char.split(",").collect();
```

Получается пример:

```
["", "2323232", "322232", "3dsfsd"]
```

Как удалить пустые значения в векторе? Понятно, что логически их туда не добавлять. Но если уже по факту они есть.

Comment: Очевидно, отфильтровать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let _strings: Vec<_> = _string_from_char.split(",").filter(|v| !v.is_empty()).collect();
```

Метод split возвращает итератор, что подсказывает, что обрабатывать строки можно тоже поточно, не складывая ссылки во временный вектор, что требует выделения памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение :

```
 _strings.retain(|value| *value != "");
```

Comment: Это не лучшее решение, потому что вы сначала населяете вектор, а потом удаляете оттуда ненужные значения.